# How to update Azure Scale Set Computer Name Prefix after creation?

Tags: azure, azure-vm-scale-set

There is a way to set the `Computer Name Prefix` at the creation time of a Scale Set. How one would be able to update the `Computer Name Prefix` after the creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you can't. The [Scale set VM computer name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-instance-ids#scale-set-vm-computer-name) or `Computer Name Prefix` cannot be updated once created. The same applies to Virtual machine names as well.